# How to make a custom Wordpress widget appear in the page/post editor and not just the global appearance settings

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am working on a custom widget plugin for Wordpress. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/) which suggests extending the `WP_Widget` class and calling `register_widget()` on the `widgets_init` action.

It works as expected when attempting to add the Widget globally from the "Appearance" settings. However, when editing a post or page, I see plenty of other widgets but not mine?

What am I missing? I've searched quite a bit online. Are theme widgets and post/page widgets two completely different things and I shouldn't be creating a `WP_Widget` to begin with?